# Piano exercises to play Chopin better

Tags: piano, exercises, chopin, romantic-period

I had been playing piano (better say: taking piano lessons) since I was a small child and to be honest, I never really liked it. I think one of the main problems was that my teacher never really allowed me to play what I wanted to - so I ended up without doing nearly any practice and sneaking from lesson to lesson. Of courses I learned a lot still, but I think there was a lot more possible...

That's why I decided to quit the piano in my late teenage years and then didn't touch the piano for a pretty long time.

My passion and rediscovery (if not to say discovery) of the piano happened with Chopin. I simply love listening to his pieces and thus started playing them to.

I taught myself some (rather simpler) Nocturnes, which I enjoy playing, but now I want to move on with some harder pieces and thus I'm searching for some exercises that I could perform regularly to improve my playing. I don't want to be specific here as I'm interested in all different kinds of exercises.
The only thing I could add to this, is whether you could list also some exercises specifically for the left hand, as my right arm is broken currently and it'll take some time to recover still.

Clarification: I do not intend to get any software or hardware recommendations (as some people apparently interpreted)

Comment: besides Hanon?…

Comment: Offtopic, but I think you can't do worse than Hanon

Comment: Please consider reposting this in the chat room.

Comment: @AndyBonner Do you think the exercises from Hanson are suited for me?

Comment: @ojs Why shouldn't I use them? Which ones are better then?

Comment: @dark_ursus there is a lot of criticism of them online so I won't repeat all of it. The main problems are that they don't exercise anything that would be useful for playing music but they are a great way to injure yourself. There are a lot of etude collections out there, and thanks to expired copyright many are available for free.

Comment: I don't understand the vtc... This is not asking for transcriptions, nor for hardware or software recommendations.

Comment: @Tom Hardware and software recs is only one of several reasons to close. Asking for recommended music or a list of music is also off topic.

Comment: Practice advice is also de facto off topic even though it's not said anywhere. If you can't see how practice advice is the same as hardware, software or apps recommendations, you haven't been around stackoverflow long enough.

Comment: @ojs Thanks for this positive view ;).

Comment: @ToddWilcox But this does not ask for music recommendation, or at least not directly. A perfectly valid answer could focus on strategies to play Chopin, say : "a bit of etudes (without necessary saying which), arpeggios and bla bla..". I agree that the op is a bit borderline but I think it could have been answered in a way that does follow the site's guidelines.

Comment: @Tom I vote based on the question, not how it could be answered. It explicitly asks for a list of exercises. Also I’m not the only one. If others agree with you, it can be reopened. Also the asker could edit it and then it could be reopened. There’s really zero point in arguing with me about it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm not arguing with you, just trying to understand as I really did not see this op as likely to be closed, hence I just explain my point of view. Close votes are also a bit opinion based, I believe it is okay to discuss it. I think we are just sometimes a bit fast in closing questions from newcomers, especially as they don't know the votes until it is already closed, this might belong more in meta..

Comment: @ToddWilcox I've never intended to ask for neither software nor hardware. I'm just asking which kind of pieces I could play and I expected an answer like the one of Tom, i.e. etudes. I  don't see how exercise is interpreted as a demand for software or hardware, at least to me this term has a broader meaning...

Comment: I closed this question because as the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page says: questions can’t ask for “recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play”.  

But when closing a post, there’s only a few options we can select; the “Recommendations” option is the closest.

Comment: @dark_ursus The reason listed for closing is not accurate. Your question is not about hardware or software and the real reason for it being closed has nothing to do with hardware or software. Asking for recommendations for pieces to play is off topic. "list also some exercises specifically for the left hand" is also off topic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Isn't it a bit hilarious, that we have such a long "discussion", while one sentence could answer my question, like Tom suggested. This way everyone wasted his/her time and nobody is happy (can't speak for you, but that's at least my opinion).  For me it's strange to declare this question off-topic. And that's one of the reasons why AI will overtake the stack exchanges in the next years (just look at stackoverflow). Because here, you spend your time trying to post a good question, which then gets simply closed.

Comment: @dark_ursus Easy there. I'm sorry you don't like our policies, but they've been in place a while and suit our needs. You can learn more in the "meta" section if you want. Meanwhile, you have high enough reputation score to post whatever you want in the chat channel, where there are no such guidelines and plenty of room for discussion. Disregard Tom's comment about hardware/software; it's not relevant.

Comment: @AndyBonner Note that I also included transcription/finding particular piece in my comments, of course this is not asking for software/hardware, but I had the feeling it was not asking for particular etude either.. Anyway ^^, my reading of the question was probably wrong